# Why body and sender are empty?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I am using this code to read emails from the server and it work except that `Sender.Address` and `Body.Text` are empty why is that ?. Here is the code:

```
var
  MsgCount : Integer;
  i        : Integer;
  FMailMessage :  TIdMessage;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  //The IdPop31 is on the form so it is constructing when the
  //form is created and so is Memo1.
  IdPOP31.Host      := 'server.com'; //Setting the HostName;
  IdPOP31.Username  := 'email@server.com';//Setting UserName;
  IdPOP31.Password  := 'xxxxxx';//Setting Password;
  IdPOP31.Port      := 110;//Setting Port;

  try
    IdPOP31.Connect();
    //Getting the number of the messages that server has.
    MsgCount := IdPOP31.CheckMessages;
    for i:= 1 to Pred(MsgCount) do
    begin
      try
        FMailMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
        IdPOP31.Retrieve(i,FMailMessage);
        Memo1.Lines.Add('=================================================');
        Memo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.From.Address);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Subject);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Sender.Address);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Body.Text);
        Memo1.Lines.Add('=================================================');
      finally
        FMailMessage.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IdPOP31.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TIdMessage.Sender` is populated only if the email has a top-level `Sender` header, which is rare. Typically the sender is in the `From` header instead.

The body content will be stored in either the `TIdMessage.Body` or `TIdMessage.MessageParts`, depending on how the email is encoded. Typically, multi-piece emails, such as those encoded with MIME, especially if they contain attachments, will use `TIdMessage.MessageParts`, whereas simple emails, like plaintext-only emails, will use `TIdMessage.Body`. So, you need to check both as needed.

For example:

```
var
  MsgCount, I: Integer;
  FMailMessage: TIdMessage;
  Body: TStrings;

  function FindTextBody(AParent: Integer): TStrings;
  var
    J: integer;
    Part: TIdMessagePart;
  begin
    Result := nil;
    // MIME parts are ordered from least complex to most complex, and can be nested,
    // so loop backwards through the parts, recursing through nested levels as needed...
    for J := Pred(FMailMessage.MessageParts.Count) downto (AParent+1) do
    begin
      Part := FMailMessage.MessageParts[J];
      if Part.ParentPart = AParent then
      begin
        if IsHeaderMediaType(Part.ContentType, 'multipart') then
        begin
          Result := FindTextBody(Part.Index);
          if Result <> nil then Exit;
        end
        else if IsHeaderMediaType(Part.ContentType, 'text') then
        begin
          Result := (Part as TIdText).Body;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  //The IdPop31 is on the form so it is constructing when the
  //form is created and so is Memo1.
  IdPOP31.Host      := 'server.com'; //Setting the HostName;
  IdPOP31.Username  := 'email@server.com';//Setting UserName;
  IdPOP31.Password  := 'xxxxxx';//Setting Password;
  IdPOP31.Port      := 110;//Setting Port;
  try
    IdPOP31.Connect();
    //Getting the number of the messages that server has.
    MsgCount := IdPOP31.CheckMessages;
    for I := 1 to Pred(MsgCount) do
    begin
      FMailMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
      try
        IdPOP31.Retrieve(I, FMailMessage);
        Memo1.Lines.Add('=================================================');
        Memo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.From.Address);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Subject);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Sender.Address);
        if FMailMessage.MessageParts.Count > 0 then
          Body := FindTextBody(-1)
        else
          Body := FMailMessage.Body;
        if Body <> nil then
          Memo1.Lines.Add(Body.Text);
        Memo1.Lines.Add('=================================================');
      finally
        FMailMessage.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IdPOP31.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I tried to do it like this `lTextPart := TIdText.Create(FMailMessage.MessageParts);`
`Memo1.Lines.Add(lTextPart.Body.text);` but I still dont get body text it is empty

Comment: @Wel when reading an email, you are not supposed to *create* a new `MessageParts` item. You are to supposed to *iterate* through the *existing* items, looking for the one you are interested in, ie one whose `ContentType` begins with `'text/...'` ('`text/plain'`, `'text/html'`, etc). MIME emails can be quite complex in structure. For instance look at [HTML Messages](https://www.indyproject.org/2005/08/17/html-messages/)

Comment: This is the page I was reading but it does not has any example how to iterate through `items` so when I iterate through `items[i]` and found content type text what property I can use to read the text ?

Comment: I just looked into clever internet components it worked fine without indy complications